# Error Xamarin forms pages say "field is already declared"

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a `Xamarin.Forms` mobile application and few pages show an error:

[image: Screenshot]

> Field _filedname is already declared

Though there is no other declaration of any field with the same name. I tried multiple names and still show the same error. Same on code behind.

Comment: Have you tried to delete `obj`, `bin`, clean solution and rebuild?

Comment: In your code-behind for this page?

Comment: this happens when you use R#. here R# gets confused because XF/VS generates .g.cs files with the declaration so R# seas them in the .g.cs and the XAML.

Comment: This happen also on code behind. I already tried by delete obj, bin. There are no R#. All is about c#

Comment: R# = Resharper a 3rd party extension vor Visual Studio. Add **[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]** to the class in the .cs